# Simplyfing complex expressions with square roots

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Simplify the expression $z =(4+4 \sqrt 3 i)^{1/2}$ so that it's in the form $z = x + iy$.

So far I got:

$$4(1+ \sqrt3 i)^{1/2}$$

But I'm unsure where to go next. I don't know you how can distribute the 1/2 since there is addition being done inside the parenthesis.
Any help?

Comment: It is $2(1+ \sqrt3 i)^{1/2}$ not $4(1+ \sqrt3 i)^{1/2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

As noted in the comment you have $(4+4 \sqrt {3} i)^{1/2}=2(1+\sqrt {3} i)^{1/2}$. Now use the [polar form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_form) for the complex number:
$
u=(1+\sqrt {3} i)= re^{i\theta} 
$
where:

$r=|u|=\sqrt{1+3}=2$ and $\theta=\arctan( \sqrt{3})= \frac{\pi}{3}$

The ([principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Principal_square_root_of_a_complex_number)) square root of u is then $\sqrt{u}=\sqrt{re^{i\theta}}=\sqrt{r}e^{i\theta/2}$

but note that in $\mathbb{C}$ we have also another square root .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the exponential form.

$z=2(1+ \sqrt3 i)^{1/2}=2\sqrt2(\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{\sqrt3}{2} i)^{1/2}=2\sqrt2(e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}})^{\frac{1}{2}}=2\sqrt2(e^{\frac{i\pi}{6}})=2\sqrt2(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+i\frac{1}{2})=\sqrt2\sqrt3+i\sqrt2=\sqrt6+i\sqrt2$

Comment: How did you get $ \sqrt 2 $ ?

Comment: $2(1+ \sqrt3 i)^{1/2}=2(2(\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{\sqrt3}{2} i))^{1/2}=2\sqrt2(\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{\sqrt3}{2} i)^{1/2}$